# Apache 2.2.31 Vhosts preventing server from starting

Tags: apache, vhosts

I'm trying to set up vhosts on a amazon AWS instance.

Whenever i add the following Vhosts config to my httpd.conf and try to restart the httpd service, it Fails, is there something i'm missing specific to apache 2.2.31?

If i remove the Vhost configuration completely the server starts ok, so i think its something specific to the actual vhost config i have.

when i do: `httpd -S` i get the following:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server mydomain.eu (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:992)
         port 80 namevhost mydomain.eu (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:992)
                 alias base5.eu
         port 80 namevhost mobile.mydomain.eu (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1001)
                 alias mobile.mydomain.eu
Syntax OK
```

Heres my vhost config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.eu
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName mydomain.eu
    ServerAlias mydomain.eu
    ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/main_error_log.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/logs/main_access_log.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.eu
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mobile"
    ServerName mobile.mydomain.eu
    ServerAlias mobile.mydomain.eu
    ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/mobile_error_log.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/logs/mobile_access_log.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Managed to fix this after commenting the lines out 1 by 1

The path i had to the Error and Custom Logs didn't exist, i created the logs folder and the httpd service was then able to start.

Comment: Does it complain about anything?

Comment: nope just says: `Starting httpd:                                            [FAILED]
` not sure if theres any logs anywhere where i can find anynmore info about httpd starting errors

Comment: Run `apachectl configtest` and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Apache has no file permissions to the Logfiles? Is this possible, or do you get an errormessage? As Root-User do the following:

```
sudo -u apache /bin/ls /var/www/logs
```

If it says something like "permission denied" than, still as root, change permissions of the Logfolder to "apache":

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/logs
```

Comment: Thanks marked your answer as correct, i had indeed not created the folder for the log files, was strange it did not report that as an error, i found it out by commenting the lines 1 by 1

Comment: Whatever redhat packaging or service tool prints out "Starting httpd: [FAILED]" is stashing the real error somewhere.  apachectl would have reported it.

Comment: thanks for that tip, i about apachectl, will remember that for the future